# Regular expression to check multiple phone number with and without extensions

Tags: angularjs, regex

In my `angular` application, I've a **text field** to get `phone number` from user.

User can enter multiple phone numbers

> separated by comma (Without country code and omitting 0 of city code)

For example if the phone number is **042-1234567**, User will enter **421234567** and multiple numbers will be like 
`421234567,421234568,...`

This regular expression working perfectly fine for me

> `^((\d{9})(,\d{9})*)$`

But there's exception that user can also add **extensions** with phone number like this

`123456786~19, 123456784~46,..`

I've tried following Regx and its working fine for these kind of inputs

> `^((\d{9}~\d{2})(,\d{9}~\d{2})*)$`

But I've to use both of these in one single field so I tried to add *OR* option and made Regx like this

> `((\d{9}~\d{2})(,\d{9}~\d{2})*)|((\d{9})(,\d{9})*)`

But its not working for both kind of inputs. e.g;

Its not validating this **123456789~12,123456789~12,123456789,123456789~12**

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: [`(?:,?(\d{9}(?:~\d{2})?))*`](https://regex101.com/r/bcFMSF/1)?

Comment: @Gurman The `(?:,?(\d{9}(?:~\d{2})?))*` will match [`,123456789~12`](https://regex101.com/r/bcFMSF/2), which is not expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yup just realised that :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use optional groups:

```
^\d{9}(?:~\d{2})?(?:,\d{9}(?:~\d{2})?)*$
      ^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yoi8vI/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{9}` - any 9 digits
- `(?:~\d{2})?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `~` - a tilde
  - `\d{2}` - any 2 digits
- `(?:,\d{9}(?:~\d{2})?)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\d{9}(?:~\d{2})?` - see above
- `$` - end of string.

Note that if you need the pattern to also match an empty string, just enclose the pattern with an optional non-capturing group, `^(?:\d{9}(?:~\d{2})?(?:,\d{9}(?:~\d{2})?)*)?$`.

Comment: what if I want to make 2 digits after tilt sign optional? means user can add either 1 or max 2 digits after tilt sign?

Comment: @NullPointer Replace `{2}` with `{1,2}`. If there can be 0, use `{0,2}`.